# Pthread failed to be created

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm currently working on a homework assignment that uses multiple threads to perform matrix multiplication but I keep getting the error message that all of the pthreads failed to be created. I have put below some of the snipets of code that have to do with allocation space for threads, allocation blocks of work for threads along with pthread_create & pthread_join then the threadMMulti is the function that each thread uses. My error is coming from this piece of code

```
 if (errorCode = pthread_create(&threadHandles[i], NULL, threadMAdd, 
                   &blocksOfWork[i]) != 0) {
      printf("pthread %d failed to be created with error code %d\n", i, errorCode);
```

So from my understanding pthread_create will return 0 if the thread is created so it's obvious that the pthread_create is failing and returning a number other then 0 so the message is displayed, I've looked into the parameters of pthread_create and I just can't seem to find where i'm going wrong. If anyone has any tips or points in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Code Snippets:

```
typedef struct {
    int threadId;
    int start_row;
    int end_row;
    int start_col;
    int end_col;
} BLOCK;

// Generate arrays for threads handles
threadHandles = (pthread_t *) malloc(numberOfThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));
blocksOfWork = (BLOCK *) malloc(numberOfThreads*sizeof(BLOCK));


// allocate block of work for each thread
for(i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
    blocksOfWork[i].threadId = i;
    blocksOfWork[i].start_row = i * rows/numberOfThreads;
    if (i == numberOfThreads -1){
        blocksOfWork[i].end_row = rows - 1;
    }
    else{
        blocksOfWork[i].end_row = (i+1)*rows/numberOfThreads -1;
    }
    blocksOfWork[i].start_col = 0;
    blocksOfWork[i].end_col = columns -1;
}
for (i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    if (errorCode = (pthread_create(&threadHandles[i], NULL, threadMMult, 
                                    &blocksOfWork[i])) != 0) {
        printf("pthread %d failed to be created with error code %d\n", i, errorCode);
    } // end if
} // end for

for (i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    if (errorCode = pthread_join(threadHandles[i], (void **) NULL) != 0) {
        printf("pthread %d failed to be joined with error code %d\n", i, errorCode);
    } // end if
} // end for

void * threadMMult(void * arg){
    BLOCK * block = (BLOCK *) arg;
    int threadId = block->threadId;
    int startRow = block->start_row;
    int endRow = block->end_row;
    int startCol = block->start_col;
    int endCol = block->end_col;
    int i, j, k;

    for (int i =startRow; i<=endRow;i++){
        for (int j =startCol; i<=endCol; j++){
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k =0; k<=endCol; k++){
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error code against errors.h?  Are you getting anything like: EAGAIN, EINVAL or EPERM?  Are you on a UNIX-like OS?  Is it failing on every thread you create, or after many are already made?   Maybe it's an operating system limit you're hitting?  You need to check the error returned.

Comment: No I have not and I am on a MAC, It's failing on every single thread i've created it gives .

Comment: @ReedSager When you compile and link the program, do you specify whatever compiler flags your platform requires for pthreads support? (Likely `-pthread`.)

Comment: When I compile the program I use -lpthread

Comment: **Make it work without multithreading first**. Only after it works in a single thread, start moving work to other threads. If the assignment forces you to use threads, perhaps ask the instructor kindly why you’re forced to write brittle and nonportable code when modern C++ standard library supports a variety of threading and parallels/asynchronous execution primitives.

Comment: The answer is because my professor is an interesting fella.. we just learned about c++ like 5 weeks ago so I'm still trying to understand everything while completing homework assignments. But thanks for the advice ill first see what I can do with a single thread

Comment: By the time I stopped my program with 1 thread the index of c[i][j] the indices were c[0][[3879] Im just confused on how the j variable got to 3879 when in the for loop is should stop at the number of rows/columns.. any ideas?

Comment: @KubaOber - many places I've worked you're coding on an old system.  Legacy code that uses pthreads, or also has to build with C.  It's the job of an engineer to make the system work, sometimes in spite of the toolset.

Comment: @Kingsley This is homework: they teach C++. C++ includes the standard library, the two aren't somehow separatable. There's zero reason to touch pthreads when teaching basic C++. It makes no pedagogical sense. The professor is "interesting" in the sense that they have lost touch with progress in C++ standardization for, oh, almost a decade... The blind leading the blind... Students in this class won't be "making systems work". They are learning the language at this point, and they should be taught modern C++ lest it's a ripoff.

Comment: @ReedSager Your middle loop is `for (int j =startCol; i<=endCol; j++)`  Note that the termination condition is based on `i`, not `j`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (under linux).
Could it be something in your `BLOCK` processing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

// Compile with: gcc -g -Wall threadmult.cpp -o threadmult -lpthread -lstdc++ 

typedef struct 
{
    int threadId;
    int start_row;
    int end_row;
    int start_col;
    int end_col;
} BLOCK;


void * threadMMult(void * arg)
{
    printf("threadMMult()- Thread=%lu with %p BEGINS\n", pthread_self(), arg);
    // TODO - some stuff
    printf("threadMMult()- Thread=%lu with %p ENDS\n", pthread_self(), arg);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int errorCode;
    int numberOfThreads = 7;
    // Generate arrays for threads handles
    pthread_t *threadHandles = (pthread_t *) malloc(numberOfThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));
    BLOCK     *blocksOfWork  = (BLOCK *) malloc(numberOfThreads*sizeof(BLOCK));


    // allocate block of work for each thread
    for (i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
        for (i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) 
        {
            errorCode = (pthread_create(&threadHandles[i], NULL, threadMMult, &blocksOfWork[i]));
            if (errorCode != 0) 
            {
                printf("pthread %d failed to be created with error code %d", i, errorCode);
                switch (errorCode)
                {
                   // Note to students - don't format your switch() like this
                   // This is OK here, because this is a quick-and-dirty debug program
                   case EAGAIN:  printf(", which is EAGAIN\n"); break;
                   case EINVAL:  printf(", which is EINVAL\n"); break;
                   case EPERM:   printf(", which is EPERM\n"); break;
                   default:   printf(", which is unknown\n"); 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I try to compile my program with gcc -o mmult -O3 mmultHW6.c -lpthread and then I try to run the program it just continues to run and doesn't stop either. I'm completely confused at this point.

Comment: Compile with: `gcc -Wall -g ...`  This gives you warnings and debug.  Don't compile with optimisation (`-O3`) until it's 110% complete.  Add some printf()s in your thread function for when your threads start and stop.  So does that mean that your threads are being created OK now ?

Comment: Well it looks like I got my threads being created okay but Now i'm getting a segmentation dump at c[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j] I think it has something to do with the way I'm interating with my for loops but I'm just not sure what the correct way to do it is

Comment: for (int i =startRow; i<=endRow;i++){
    for (int j =0; i<=startCol; j++){
      C[i][j] = 0;
      for(int k =0; k<=; k++){
        C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
      }
    }
  }

}

Comment: Yeah, you're running off the end of your allocated data somehow.  Maybe print out the rows and cols etc. at each stage of the process.  Do you have `valgrind`?  It's a great debugger for these sorts of issues?

Comment: I just installed valgrind and used this command in the terminal  gcc -Wall -g mmultHW6.c -o memcheck but still didn't offer me a lot of help just says segmentation fault 11: From what I know its coming form the C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]. I think i'm just having a hard time how matrix multiplication works using multiple threads, I'm not even sure what i'm suppose to be iterating over if each thread has its own block of data its working on.

Comment: try: valgrind ./memcheck

Comment: Change your `C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]` to be `printf("%lu - C[%d][%d] += A[%d][%d]*B[%d][%d]\n", pthread_self(), i,j,i,k,k,j);` - verify every index is within `C[][]`.  Output the result to a file, then `sort` it, this will give you a log by thread-id OR set the number of threads to 1.  Yeah, do that.

Comment: By the time I  forced my program to stop C indices were [125][1370] Now i'm even more confused..